# Using Java Stream API in already multi-threaded environment

Tags: java-8, java-stream

My application has its own thread pool(myThreadPool) and I am assigning one of its threads(Producer) to read a file via java stream API. But in runtime stream is lost somewhere and never reaches the print method. But when I run the stream in single threaded environment it works. Does it happen because java stream Api uses its own thread pool underneath or is this conceptually wrong?

```
public class Processor {

  public void process() {
    ExecutorService myThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    myThreadPool.execute(new Producer());
  }

  private class Producer implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("Path"))) {
            System.out.println(lines.count());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I don’t see any reason why this shouldn’t complete. However, this isn’t your actual code, i.e. you don’t show how you handle potential `IOException`s or where `filePath` does come from, so there are several things which can go wrong in the code parts you haven’t shown.

Comment: Yeah, I just posted required parts but  now updated to avoid confusions ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you have happen. but I can give you an advice (*maybe your program exited and Producer is not terminated*). copy this code and see what wrong of your code.

```
public class Processor {

    public void process() {
        ExecutorService myThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        try {
            myThreadPool.execute(new Producer());
            Thread.currentThread().join();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class Producer implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("Path"))) {
                System.out.println(lines.count());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
public class Processor {

    public void process() {
        ExecutorService myThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        try {
            myThreadPool.submit(() -> {
                new Producer().run();
                return null;
            }).get();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class Producer implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("Path"))) {
                System.out.println(lines.count());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your guess is right. I just replaced the code and it worked. Thanks. So I suppose its a verdict between different behaviours of execute() and submit().get() methods. Need to rationalise a reason.

Comment: @Malith they were the same, only sutmit().get() blocked until the value returned.

Comment: yeah exactly. Not sure why they behave differently.

Comment: @Malith you use the code of the second section, it also can print lines. maybe you need to see some thread article first.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually I cannot use Thread().join() or get() as it blocks the next thread being executed if you have multiple tasks. But I found the root cause and its something else. I was using Junit to execute the code and Junit runtime exits regardless of child threads being executed still which leads to this kind of behaviour. Using ThreadPool shutdown() in conjunction with awaitTermination() solved the issue.